# Celery pool statistic fields

Tags: celery

I'm trying to understand what the celery statistic `pool::writes::avg` is showing. From the celery documentation on `writes`:

> Specific to the prefork pool, this shows the distribution of writes to each process in the pool when using async I/O.

My understanding is that `all` is the percentage of total tasks completed by a given process, `raw` is the task count completed by a given process. But what is `avg` telling me?

A subset of my `celery -A proj inspect stats` is:

```
        "pool": {
            "max-concurrency": 2,
            "max-tasks-per-child": "N/A",
            "processes": [
                23743,
                23744
            ],
            "put-guarded-by-semaphore": false,
            "timeouts": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "writes": {
                "all": "58.06%, 41.94%",
                "avg": "48.39%",
                "inqueues": {
                    "active": 0,
                    "total": 2
                },
                "raw": "18, 13",
                "strategy": "fair",
                "total": 31
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, the "pool.writes" statistic is *specific to the prefork pool, this shows the distribution of writes to each process in the pool when using async I/O* (from Celery docs)

From bin/worker.py:

`'avg': per(total / len(self.write_stats) if total else 0, total),`

where `write_stats` seems to be a collections.Counter keeping track of the processes in the pool. per(v, total) is a function that returns a string containing the `v/total` as percentage.  I wish someone with knowledge of Celery internals give more details about this.